# Is it possible to setup "link level tracking" for goals / goal flow in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, goals

I've got two buttons on my homepage, which when clicked lead through to the same lead capture form page. Accordingly a user can flow through the lead capture form in either of the following paths:

1. `[Button at **TOP** of homepage] -> lead form page -> thank you page`
2. `[Button at **BOTTOM** of homepage] -> lead form page -> thank you page`

The homepage, lead form page, and the thank you page are the same in both user flow examples, the only difference is the user flow starting with the button at the top or bottom of the homepage.

Using goals and goal flow in google analytics i would like to track how users flow through the site, but in BOTH of the above examples the flow would be the same eg. `homepage -> lead form page -> thank you page`.

Is there a way to get internal link level tracking for goals / goal flow in google analytics? eg. a separate goal flow for both 1) and 2) above?

One work around I've thought of would be have a separate lead form and separate thank you page for each link and then track the different flows that way, but it would become really messy really quickly, with lots of very similar pages to update and manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically handle this by passing a parameter through the lead form page to the thank you page and setting up two goal funnels in Google Analytics:

1. [Button at **TOP** of homepage] -> `/lead-form?from=home-top` -> `/thank-you?from=home-top`
2. [Button at **BOTTOM** of homepage] -> `/lead-form?from=home-bottom` -> `/thank-you?from=home-bottom`

In addition to tagging the home page buttons, you need to modify the lead form to pass the parameter through, and create multiple goals in analytics.

Comment: thanks, how would i "modify the lead form to pass the parameter through" and where appending these additional parameters to the URLs could this create issues where a search engine would see the pages as duplicate content, if so how should i handle this ?

Comment: The lead-form would have to look for the `from` parameter on the URL and append it to the thank you page link when it builds it.  Search engines could see it as duplicate content, but these types of pages should typically be noindexed anyway.  If you don't already have noindex tags on your thank you page, you should definitely do so.  Your lead form page should either have noindex or canonical tags pointing to one version of it.